# rcleartool: Can I list directory contents without downloading the files?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I'm accessing a ClearCase VOB remotely and I hope to scriptify something with rcleartool 7.1.2.

There is a directory tree with many large files in it, and I hope to avoid unnecessarily fetching them all from the remote server into a snapshot view.  I see how to fetch an individual file, but I don't see how to get a directory listing of the files that are there, so the script knows which individual files there are to process, without populating the snapshot view by downloading the whole set of large files.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: your question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you not preview the fetch (considering CCRC 7.x doesn't include dynamic view), but you cannot limit what is fetched even if you could.
That would involve [`rcleartool setcs`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-64&lang=en), in order to associate to a web view a list load rules, but it is supported only [since CCRC 8.0.0.3](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728).

Comment: Thanks!  Sadly: (1) I believe the server's version limits me to rcleartool 7.1.2. (2) My issue is not how to limit my loading to a set of files, but how to find out the set of files that must be loaded -- how to get a list of all the files, so that the script can pick out the subset that must be loaded.

Comment: @JohnK you could use dynamic views... but they are not supported in CCRC 7.x (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233091)